# How to type exponential notation and multiply sign in R

Tags: r

I want R to write the following:

[image]

My requirements are:

1. The multiplication sign should not be "*", but the real multiplication sign as above;
2. Scientific notation should not be expressed in 5e6, but rather 6 raised to the power of 10.

What is the R code? I feel the `expression` function or `formatC` or `format` should be used, but I am not sure how to do it. Thank you.

Comment: Not possible...as far as I know. And even If you do it would be a string, not a number

Comment: Why do you need this? What are you trying to do?

Comment: What would you want this for? - (Sorry if you know this and my response is silly): If it is for output (rather then the calculation) RMarkdown with the LaTeX math-typesetting would do this: $5 \times 10^6$

Comment: Where do you "want R to write" it?

Comment: In a plot title or label this will work:  `expression(5 %*% 10^6)`.

Comment: I want to label axis ticks for my plot. I wish to customize axis tick labels instead of using default tick labels. If I am using defalt tick labels, I could use `expression`, but since I wish to customize tick position, I am not sure how to create corresponding tick labels with exponential scientific notation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```r
x <- c(5*(10^(1:5)))
plot(x, x, xaxt="n", log="x", las = 2)
labels <- parse(text = gsub("e\\+", " %*% 10^", sprintf("%.0e", x)))
axis(1, at = x, labels = labels)
```

[image: base graphics plot with expression axis ticks]

Thanks to @VincentGuillemot for a simplification.

Comment: Great answer! If I may, you can shorten it a little bit: `labels <- parse(text = gsub("e\\+", " %*% 10^", sprintf("%.0e", x)))`, I think it would still works as intended.